# error in populating a drop down menu in php

Tags: php

Here is my function that should populate a drop down list dynamically. But its not working and i cant seem to find out why.
Don't know how lame the answer might be but i m a newbie and seem to be struggling a lot with PHP.

Thanks in advance.

```
$mydata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scholarship_details);

while($record=mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
echo "<OPTION VALUE=".$record['s_name'].">".$record['s_name']."</OPTION>";
} ?>
```

error i m getting is 
   `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'VALUE' (T_STRING)`

resolved.. knew it had to be been some lame problem. thanks guys

Comment: $mydata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scholarship_details"); quotes mising in ur query

Answer (score 0):

use missed double quotes here.

```
$mydata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scholarship_details");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the modified code.

```
<?php
$mydata = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM scholarship_details");//Quotes not properly closed

while($record=mysql_fetch_array($mydata)){
echo "<OPTION VALUE=".$record['s_name'].">".$record['s_name']."</OPTION>";//Quotes not properly closed
}
?>
```